# Is the line integral bounded wrt the $L^2$-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Question**

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a bounded domain, and let $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to \Omega$ be a smooth and closed path in $\Omega$. Can we find a constant $C >0$ such that for every vector field $v \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^0(\overline{\Omega})$ with $\text{curl}\, v = 0$ in $\Omega$ there holds
$$
\bigg\lvert \int_0^1 v(\gamma(t)) \cdot \dot\gamma(t) \, dt  \bigg\rvert \leq C \int_{\Omega} \lvert v(x) \rvert^2 \, dx\, ?
$$

**Attempt**

To be honest, I do not know how to tackle this problem. I do, however, believe that such a constant exist: the vector field $v$ is curl-free and so the line integral does not change if we deform $\gamma$ in such a way that we stay in the same homotopy class. So maybe we can take curves $\gamma^{\prime}$ that are parallel and homotopic to $\gamma$. But at the moment I have no idea how to come from a line integral to an integral over $\Omega$. Maybe, someone of you has an idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a "trace inequality"; in this context, a "trace" is the restriction of a function to a lower dimensional manifold. You need to provide some Sobolev regularity on v.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. Define
$$
v_n(x) = x\cdot \|x\|_2^n
$$
with $\Omega =$ closed unit ball, $\gamma$ a path in the boundary of the ball. Then for $n\to\infty$ the $L^2$-norm on the rhs in your inequality vanishes, while the curve integral stays constant.

If the curve is required to stay in the interior of the domain, then set $\Omega=B_2(0)$ and take a curve in the boundary of the unit ball again, modify $v_n$ to
$$
v_n(x) = x\cdot \phi(\|x\|_2^n),
$$
where $\phi$ is a smooth function such that $\phi(t)=1$ for all $t\ge1$ and $\phi(t)\ge t$ for $t\in [0,1)$.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that $\gamma$ should lie in the open domain, too. (I haven't bothered to think if you can easily fix the example for that to be the case)

Comment: @T_M see edit, one can use a cut-off function

Comment: @daw Thank you very much for your answer. I do see why the $L^2$-norm (in the first example) converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. But the integral over a path $\gamma$ in the boundary of $B_1(0)$ vanishes as well. So where is the contradiction?

Comment: @MichelC oh yes, the boundary integral is then zero. But maybe you can use the idea to construct a real counterexample?